# Check if Protection Status is On then disable Bitlocker using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Hi I am trying to make a script that will check Bitlocker status. If Protection status is On, it will disable Bitlocker.

```
Get-BitLockerVolume | select ProtectionStatus | ForEach-Object {$_.ProtectionStatus
    if($_.ProtectionStatus -like "On")
    {
        Disable-BitLocker -MountPoint $_.MountPoint
    }
    else
    {
        Break
    }
}
```

but I got message issues

```
Disable-BitLocker : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'MountPoint'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:4 char:39
+         Disable-BitLocker -MountPoint $_.MountPoint
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Disable-BitLocker], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Disable-BitLocker
```

How can I fix the script? Thanks

Comment: You've selected only "ProtectionStatus" earlier in the pipeline, so now that's all that's left. There are no other properties sent to the next step. You should either remove the `select` or make it `select MountPoint,ProtectionStatus`

Comment: Thank you. After added  `MountPoint, ProtectionStatus`. It shows another issue `Enable-BitLocker : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:4 char:9
+         Disable-BitLocker -MountPoint $_.MountPoint`

Comment: Where is the `Enable-BitLocker` coming from? I only see `Disable-BitLocker` in the code here.